# kured not cordoning aks nodes

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-apiserver

we are using aks private cluster of version 1.22.6 enabled with AzureCNI type. Andd our nodepools are using the image version as below.

```
Name       NodeImageVersion
---------  ---------------------------------------
devpool   AKSUbuntu-1804gen2containerd-2022.02.07
system     AKSUbuntu-1804gen2containerd-2022.02.07
```

So we introduced kured installation to manage the nodes image update in a scheduled way and followed the document to install the components. https://anchortagdev.com/schedule-azure-kubernetes-service-aks-cluster-updates-with-kured/

verified that all components are created and the kured daemonset pods are running in all nodes.

below is the the yaml got by kubect edit command for the kured daemonset

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  annotations:
    deprecated.daemonset.template.generation: "6"
  name: kured
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: kured
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: kured
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - /usr/bin/kured
        - --period=1m
        - --start-time=10am
        - --end-time=1pm
        - --time-zone=Local
        - --ds-name=kured
        - --ds-namespace=kube-system
        - --reboot-days=mon
        env:
        - name: KURED_NODE_ID
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        image: docker.io/weaveworks/kured:master-f6e4062
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: kured
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      hostPID: true
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      serviceAccount: kured
      serviceAccountName: kured
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      tolerations:
      - effect: NoSchedule
        key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
  updateStrategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 0
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
```

But eventhough we made the period to 1 minute, the nodes are still showing as "Ready for Scheduling" and we expected this should be cordoned by the kured automatically as its having outdated image and verified that the /var/run/reboot-required files is existing in all these niodes.

below is the output from the deaemon set pods.

```
time="2022-06-24T09:24:12Z" level=info msg="Kubernetes Reboot Daemon: master-f6e4062"
time="2022-06-24T09:24:12Z" level=info msg="Node ID: aks-devpool-1xxxxxxx-vmssxxxxxxx"
time="2022-06-24T09:24:12Z" level=info msg="Lock Annotation: kube-system/kured:weave.works/kured-node-lock"
time="2022-06-24T09:24:12Z" level=info msg="Reboot Sentinel: /var/run/reboot-required every 1m0s"
time="2022-06-24T09:24:12Z" level=info msg="Blocking Pod Selectors: []"
time="2022-06-24T09:24:12Z" level=info msg="Reboot on: ---Mon--------------- between 10:00 and 13:00 UTC"
```

Answer (score 0):

Had this an issue similar to this one a while back which was resolved by updating images on pods using az cli commands. Then they were back to normal after that...
using:

```
az aks nodepool upgrade \
    --resource-group myResourceGroup \
    --cluster-name myAKSCluster \
    --name mynodepool \
    --node-image-only
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/node-image-upgrade#upgrade-a-specific-node-pool

Not sure if there has been an update on AKS side after the 1.22 upgrade, but this was connected to a cluster upgrade for us.